# how to post array of objects in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Post array of objects in angular js
my json :-

```
 invoices:{
invoice_no: 221
    items: {
    item_name: aircel
    quantity: 2
    }
}
```

This is my html coding :-

```
<form ng-submit="addInvoice()" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
<label> items</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="invoices.item_name" id="item_name">
<input type="text" ng-model="invoices.quantity" id="quantity">
<input type="text" ng-model="invoices.less" id="less">
</div>
```

in the above coding how to post item_name. i want post items of objects.

Comment: please describe your problem more specifically

Comment: i want post array of objects

Comment: in my form i post array of objects

Answer (score 0):

Simply inject the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service and `post`:

```
$http.post('/someUrl', data).success(successCallback);
```

Comment: <input type="test" ng-model="invoices.item_name"> i want this coding

Comment: if you want to post something to somewhere(your server) you need a url. The data you send can be a string, an array, an object etc..

Comment: in my form without array of objects fields are stored but with array of objects are not stored